# How to find the difference between the count of two different sets that belong to the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the count of votes in my blog, which equals to the difference between the vote up times and the vote down times.

All votes are stored in the database in the table `votes`. If the `votetype` field in the table equals 0 it means that a user has voted the post up. And if it equals 1 then a user has voted the post down.

I want to find the difference between the voteup count and the votedown count. Something like this query.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(
        SELECT * FROM votes WHERE votetype=0
    )
    -
    COUNT(
        SELECT * FROM votes WHERE votetype=1
    ) 
FROM votes WHERE postid=1
```

But this query is giving me a syntax error.

How can I find the number of votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. For upvotes you assign `1` to each row and `-1` for the downvotes. Sum each of them and then add up.

```
SELECT 
sum(case when votetype=0 then 1 else 0 end) + 
sum(case when votetype=1 then -1 else 0 end)
FROM votes 
WHERE postid=1
```

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. Except when the table is empty, it returns NULL not 0. How can this special case be handled?